# How to create a agent class for another class without repeating all functions

Tags: java, design-patterns, proxy

I want to create a agent class for Class1:

```
Public class Class1 {
  public void log(String str){
       ....
  }

  public void log(String str1, Object obj){
       ....
  }

  .... 
}
```

Class1 has lots of log functions with the same name "log" but with different parameters. I want to create a agent/proxy class for Class1 but do not want to repeat all its functions. I have tried the following way, it did not work.

```
public class agentForClass1 {
   protected Class1 obj1;

   public log(Object... objs){
      obj1.log(objs);
   }
}
```

Can you help? Is this possible in Java?

Comment: Or if there is any other way to achieve the same aim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is :) You could use java Reflection capabilities.

This a sketch that i've tested for the definition of Class1 you gave. The trick is the `isInstance` method.

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Class1Agent {

    private Class1 class1 = new Class1();

    public void log(Object... objects) throws IllegalArgumentException,
            IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        Method[] methods = class1.getClass().getMethods();
        for (Method method : methods) {
            Class<?>[] parameterTypes = method.getParameterTypes();
            if (objects.length == parameterTypes.length) {
                int i = 0;
                while (i < objects.length
                        && parameterTypes[i].isInstance(objects[i])) {
                    ++i;
                }
                if (i == objects.length) {
                    method.invoke(class1, objects);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is an interesting idea of using reflect. Have you tested the efficiency cost of using reflect? Say 2 times slower or 10 times slower than traditional delegation?

Comment: No, i've not tested that, but i supposse it can be quite high (anyway i think it should be measured first in the context of your application). If you don't want to reimplement all the methods, i don't know how it could be done while maintining as small footprint a footprint as a couple of function calls..